# Are Holomorphic functions the same as $C^{\infty}$ functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is saying a function is holomorphic the same as saying it is a $C^{\infty}$ function? If not what is the difference?

Comment: Yes, but just being differentiable is a **very** strong restriction for complex functions, so it is worthwhile using a different terminology.

Comment: @copper.hat Doesn't the Cauchy Riemann condition alone implies that the function is complex differentiable? (I am a physics graduate student, so my terminologies can be a bit off)

Comment: I mean complex differentiable, that is $\lim_{ h \to 0} {f(z+h)-f(z) \over h }$ where $z$ is complex and the domain is open. In this case (complex) differentiable (also holomorphic, analytic) is equivalent to the function being real differentiable (with respect to the $x,y$ in the $x+iy$ sense) and satisfying the CR equations.

Comment: Being complex differentiable is a very strong constraint on the function because the 'increment' $h$ in my previous comment is complex, so it can approach $0$ from any direction. It seems innocuous, but is a really big restriction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in the sense that it can be proved that a function $f\colon D\longrightarrow\mathbb C$, where $D$ is a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb C$, is holomorphic if and only if it is a complex $C^\infty$ function. That's a non-trivial theorem.

Comment: u shud specify "complex $C^\infty$"

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: It is also equivalent to $\mathbf C$-differentiable.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos any link to the theorem or suggested reference?

Comment: Take a llok at [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions).

Answer (score 0):

$f(z) = \bar z$ is contiuous but it is not holomorphic.

But does it have continuous derivatives?  The definition of the complex derivative is a bit more restrictive than the single variable derivative or the partial derivative.

$f'(z) = \lim_\limits{|\Delta z|\to 0} \frac {f(z + \delta z) - f(z)}{\Delta z}$

In order for this limit to exist, it must converge along all paths in the complex plane.

This means that the Cauchy-Reimann equations must be satisfied.

$f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)\\
\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac {\partial v}{\partial y}\\
\frac {\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac {\partial v}{\partial x}$

So, yes a function is holomorphic if it is complex differentiable.  And if a function is complex differentiable, it is infinitely differentiable.  This also implies that a Taylor series exists.